# nuxt i18n change url on fetch

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

When I fetch some api url from `domain/{locale}/` to (example) `/__cache/` > url transformed to `/{locale}/__cache/`. Using native fetch from browser console.

Any ideas to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you set the `defaultLocale` in your `nuxt-i18n`?

Comment: @DengSihan of course